# Forward converter magnetizing current and active clamp

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

Can somebody explain why the magnetizing current starts at a negative value?

[image]

Also, the highlighted part below kind of gives me a hard time to comprehend. Does this mean that the voltage across the capacitor is changing from one value to another instantly when S2 closes? I was taught that capacitor voltages can't instantaneously change. Also what does having large value of this cap have to do with the voltage being constant? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You've asked 13 questions now and only one of them has been marked as accepted by you. I see other questions with good answer so, have you forgotten to do this on the more recent questions? A slip of the mind?

Comment: @Paumdrdo: Could you please let me know which textbook is this from?

Answer (score 3):

> Can somebody explain why the magnetizing current starts at a negative value?

It starts at a negative value because it finished at a negative value the previous cycle, and does not change instantly.

These waveforms are drawn assuming the converter has been operating for a while, the so called steady state. At first switch-on, the current starts from zero, and will swing up to 2*I<sub>m</sub> during the first half cycle. What happens next to get to the steady state is more complicated than simply being in the steady state, which is why treatments like you're reading ignore it.

The resistance of the primary generates a voltage across it which tends to reduce the effect of this switch-on transient. The higher current may or may not saturate the core. If it does, a very large current will then be drawn, which will settle the converter down to the steady state faster. Iron cores tend to be run close to saturation, so are likely to saturate on switch-on. Ferrite cores tend to run below saturation, so may well not saturate on switch-on.

> I was taught that capacitor voltages can't instantaneously change. Also what does having large value of this cap have to do with the voltage being constant?

You were taught correctly. The capacitor voltage does not jump discontinuously, changing only as current flows in or out. The larger the value of the capacitor, the less the voltage changes for any given change of charge. As the capacitor becomes very large, the voltage change at its terminals becomes very small, eventually changing little enough to be called 'constant', at least constant with respect to the other voltage changes happening in the circuit, and over the timescale of one switching cycle.

For some reason, the author has chosen not to graph the capacitor or inductor voltage, perhaps thinking it's obvious. It is for him, but not for all of his readers. What will happen is that the voltage on the capacitor will adjust itself over a large number of cycles so that the average voltage across the primary is zero.

Comment: The graph for the magnetizing current  seems to cross zero at exactly half of the first interval can you explain why is that happening? Same phenomena happens during the second interval it crosses zero at exactly half of that interval.

Comment: @Paumdrdo ... because in the ideal case, the waveform is symmetric about zero. The average voltage across the inductor has to be zero, otherwise the current would be unbounded. With symmetric (well, anti-symmetric) peaks, it has to zero cross at the mid-points of the intervals. With a smaller C, so with changing reset voltage, so with non-linear fall of current, the zero crossings would be displaced slightly from midpoints, but the average voltage waveform would still be zero. A bit of primary resistance developing a voltage as the load current flowed would also shift the zero crossings.