# Looking for a good text book describing active clamp forward converter

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, isolation

Can anyone refer a standard text book for understanding Active-clamp forward converter in detail?
I could only find application notes and datasheets on this till now.

I have gone through below books- None of them have any reference on active-clamp forward converter.

1. Fundamentals of Power electronics - Erickson
2. Power electronics Handbook - Rashid
3. Power electronics -Converters Application and design -Ned Mohan
4. A to Z switching power supplies -Sanjay Maniktala

Specifically Iam looking for the textbook referred in this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/517093/forward-converter-magnetizing-current-and-active-clamp).

Comment: This can be useful https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva591/snva591.pdf?ts=1652026535225&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.be%252F https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua535a/slua535a.pdf?ts=1652026686053&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.be%252F

Comment: What textbook in that question? If you start by giving the title we may be able to help.

Comment: You can have a look at my [book](https://www.amazon.com/Switch-Mode-Power-Supplies-Second-Edition/dp/0071823468/ref=dp_ob_image_bk) dedicated to switching converters, I speak about the ACF. I also published a series of articles on the subject in [How2Power](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1402/articles/H2PToday1402_design_ON%20Semiconductor.pdf?NOREDIR=1).

Comment: https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468 highly recommended

Comment: @Solar Mike: Iam not sure of the book title or author. I was wondering if anyone could identify the text book.